# ¿Porqué la base de datos me confunde un valor a buscar por una tabla?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Trabajando en Python, estoy teniendo problemas para encontrar algún dato en una base de datos. La Base se llama "Chat.db", tiene una tabla llamada "APELLIDOS" y una columna llamada "Apellido". 
La consulta queda: **'SELECT * FROM APELLIDOS WHERE Apellido = HOLA'**.
Los apellidos están guardados en mayúscula y todas las palabras a buscar también las paso a mayúsculas. Pero como busca datos de un texto, entonces no siempre son apellidos los que busca, y por eso en el ejemplo puse "HOLA".
Ahora bien, cuando ejecuto la búsqueda me sale el error:
**No such column: HOLA**
Saben qué cosas pueden generar éste error?. **ADICIONAL:** Estoy compliando con Python 3.6, 3.8 en windows y linux lite. Debido a que quiero que sea funcional en ambas plataformas estoy programando para los 2, y todo me funciona correcto salvo ésto.
Ahora no corro más el programa sino que intento ejecutar éste problema para resolverlo. A continuación la
FUNCIÓN QUE PREPARA EL PEDIDO

```
def Reg_Un_param(BaseDeDatos, Tabla, Columna, DatoCoincide):
sql = 'SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {} = {}'.format( Tabla, Columna, DatoCoincide)
Resultado = Realiza_consulta( BaseDeDatos, sql)
return Resultado
```

FUNCIÓN QUE REALIZA LA CONSULTA

```
def Realiza_consulta( BaseDatos, query, parameters = ()):
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, BaseDatos)
# Realizamos la conección y la almacenamos en la variable conn
with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
    # Cursor, es una propiedad que nos indica en qué posición estamos dentro de la base de datos, y lo almacenamos en la variable Cur
    Cur = conn.cursor()
    # Execute, es la función que realiza la consulta, y los resultados obtenidos serán almacenados en la variable resultado
    resultado = Cur.execute(query, parameters)
    # Se guardan los cambios
    conn.commit()
    # Creamos una lista en la que se devuelven los resultados
    row = ['']
    # Si hubieron resultados, se cargan en la lista
    for pos in resultado:
        row = [pos[0]]
    # Cerramos la conexión con la base de datos
    Cur.close()
    return row
```

Y AHORA PARA PROBAR ESTOY LLAMANDO A LA FUNCIÓN DE ÉSTA MANERA:

```
print(Reg_Un_param('Chat.db', 'APELLIDOS', 'Apellido', 'HOLA'))
```

Comment: El parámetro que contiene el valor del campo a buscar es considerado como un nombre de columna, como le indica el error (No such column: HOLA). Eso es porque no pone ese valor entre comillas ya que es un string... Es decir, que en realidad la consulta debería quedar así: SELECT * FROM APELLIDOS WHERE Apellido = 'HOLA'   (fijate que en tu caso HOLA no esta entre comillas)

Comment: Entiendo, me ayudas a comprender el error, pero cómo hago para agregarle dichas comillas?, porque yo le cargo los valores en la línea: sql = 'SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {} = {}'.format( Tabla, Columna, DatoCoincide)

Comment: Pensé que intentarías deducir eso por ti mismo un rato... a continuación tienes las posibles soluciones.

Comment: Perdón, he estado probando muchas combinaciones y no encontraba la forma de quitar el error. Acabo de ver la solución y no pensé que podía agregarle comillas al enunciado de la consulta, sin que éstas mismas no interfieran en la consulta. Es decir, que pensaba que si ponía algo así como '{}', eso me daría como resultado el intentar buscar un texto así: {}. Es por ésto que supuse de manera errónea tal solución. Pero gracias por todo. Se que encontrar la solución por uno mismo hace que la recuerdes aún más, pero ya me había cansado. Saludos y muchas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Entiendo que a veces, después de probar mucho, se pierde algo la paciencia. Yo simplemente quise orientarte con un comentario inicial. Y poner una solución más tarde (si no das con la solución), o darte la posibilidad de poner la que tu encontrases a partir de la orientación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te decía en mi comentario inicial, el error es causado porque el parámetro que contiene el valor del campo a buscar, es considerado como un nombre de columna de la tabla consultada.

Esto se puede ver del propio error que indicaste: **(No such column: HOLA)**

Es decir, que en realidad la consulta que deseas realizar debería quedar así:

**`SELECT * FROM APELLIDOS WHERE Apellido = 'HOLA'`**

Para solucionar este tipo de problemas, poner las comillas dentro del `string` construido, existen varias soluciones posibles. Te propongo un par de ellas:

*a)* Usando `\` para indicar que el símbolo siguiente es un carácter de la secuencia que no debe ser interpretado como código.

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {} = \'{}\''.format( Tabla, Columna, DatoCoincide)
```

*b)* Usar `"` para crear el `string`, así las comillas simples no serán interpretadas como código.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {} = '{}'".format( Tabla, Columna, DatoCoincide)
```